# Запятая перед "примерно"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения

> Я выбрал его ещё тогда, примерно в 2004 – 2007 годах.

Ставится ли запятая перед "примерно" в данном случае?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая ставится.

*Я выбрал его ещё **тогда, примерно в 2004–2007 годах.***

[**Уточняющие члены предложения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118,4) (Розенталь)

> Обособляются (выделяются запятыми, реже — тире) слова и словосочетания, уточняющие смысл предшествующих слов (уточнение — это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому). Чаще всего уточняются обстоятельства и определения.
> <...>
> 2. Уточняющие обстоятельства времени: <...> ***Теперь же, после** половодья, это была река саженей в шесть* (Ч.)...

P. S. Промежуток между годами обозначается с помощью тире **без пробелов** ([Временные периоды и числовые интервалы](https://kerchtt.ru/mezhdu-slovami-tire-ili-defis-po-gostu-vremennye-periody-i-chislovye/)).